# Jquery, 'this' inside function always returns document

Tags: jquery, pug

```
$("#oulist li").filter(() => {
  console.log(this);
}).css("background-color", "red")
```

Hi, Whenever I try to use this function, this always returns as document. I am not sure whether this has something to do with pug.js.

Comment: The function doesn't have keyword `return`. I see there's `filter()` ok, what are you expecting what do you get instead?

Comment: Please be more specific of what it's returning and what's the error in logs?

Comment: @Dhaval Jardosh The console is logging '#document' rather than the '#oulist li" that i expected. I am not trying to return anything at the moment because of the 'this' variable acting strange.

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function). Also note you're using an arrow function instead of a normal function, which changes the dynamic of `this`.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Thank you, forgot about the arrow function for a while.

Comment: It should give you window object, because the arrow function uses the (lexical scope) parent context as `this`. If you use a normal function then `this` will give you the targeted `html` element.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is you are using the newer ES6 arrow functions which don't use `this` as you would expect. Change `() => { }` to the traditional `function() {}` notation to see the difference. Read more about the arrow functions [here](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4).

You also forgot to `return this;` to return the `<li>` elements for `.css();`

```js
$("#oulist li").filter(function(foo) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log("foo: " + foo); // Don't really need foo, but included.
  return this; // return <li> back to be ran with .css();
}).css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="oulist">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

because it reads all document so you can specifies what you need by his class and his attribute 
example

suppose you classify your element with id "oulist li"  as "newClass":

$( "li" )
  .filter( ".newClass" )
    .css( "border-color", "red" );